# parseInt values no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX request that does nothing and I don't know why.
It doesn't give me any error.my code:

```
$("#idButton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=EUR",
            data: {},
            success: function(data) {
                     $("#idUsd").val(parseInt(data['rates']['USD']) * 
                     parseInt($("#idEur").val())); //I think the error is here
            },

            error: function(x, e) { console.log(e); }
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8SyM.png)

Answer (score 1):

In Success, you need to check the `data` and `$("#idEur").val()` for **`undefined`** or **`null`**, then you start your implementation.

```
$("#idButton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=EUR",
            data: {},
            success: function(data) {
                if((data != undefined) && (data != null) && 
                      (data['rates'] != undefined) && (data['rates'] != null) && 
                     (data['rates']['USD'] != undefined) && (data['rates']['USD'] != null) && 
                    (data['rates']['USD'] != "") && ($("#idEur").val() != undefined) && 
                    ($("#idEur").val() != null) && ($("#idEur").val() != "")) {

                     $("#idUsd").val(parseInt(data['rates']['USD']) * 
                     parseInt($("#idEur").val())); //I think the error is here
               }
            },

            error: function(x, e) { console.log(e); }
    });
});
```

Comment: @IrinaFarcau - Check the ajax call is returning **data** with **200 Response code** by using Inspect Elements.

Comment: Yess, but how to resolve it? 200 response code was also returning in the first place.

Comment: @IrinaFarcau can you please take the snapshot and paste it in your question block including that inspect element ajax call trace...

Comment: done. So when I enter 1 in the first textbox, in the secondtextbox should appear the result. but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request is inside a `click` handler. I believe you have defined the `click` handler before you have actually added `#idButton` to the HTML. You need to make sure that the element already exists when the handler is defined, possibly putting it into `$(function() {})` or to use `.on()` which will register the handler in future element creation as well.

**Case 1:**

You have a `script` tag inside your head and you define `#idButton` inside `body`. In this case this code should solve the problem:

```
$(function() {
    $("#idButton").click(function(e) {/*Your handler*/});
});
```

**Case 2:**

`#idButton` is created and added at runtime. In that case

```
$('body).on('click', '#idButton', function(e) {/*Your handler*/});
```

should solve the problem. Ideally switch `body` to the lowest node selector in the tree already existent when you define the handler and which contains the button.

Comment: well, i tried to delete the button and it gives me Nan

Comment: so the problem must be in the function(data)

Comment: @IrinaFarcau, you stated "I have an AJAX request that does nothing and I don't know why.". If the problem is inside the success function, which is a callback for the AJAX request, then the statement is mistaken, since the request has been sent to the server, which responded.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX doesn't support cross domain calls, for security reasons.

Build a Proxy, so you can call a url on your domain.
In php, you could create a file proxy.php:

```
<?php
    readfile('https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=EUR');
    exit;
```

Then use this new url:

```
url: "proxy.php",
```

Hope that helps